# How to change the shape of dot in geom_dotplot in R?

Tags: r, shapes, dot

when working on ggplot()+geom_dotplot(), I wonder how to change the filled dot to the filled square

Comment: From [`?geom_dotplot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=ggplot2%3A%3Ageom_dotplot): *"'geom_dotplot()' understands the following aesthetics ... 'x', 'y', 'alpha', 'colour', 'fill', 'group'"*. It seems that if you want to change the shape, you may need to write a new function.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a total hack, but it will do what you want

```r
# plot just the dotplot
p <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1.5, dotsize = 1) +
  ylim(-0.1, 1.1)


# this is the "instructions" of the plot
gpb <- ggplot_build(p)


# gpb$data is a list, you need to use the first element
gpb$data[[1]] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, stackpos/max(stackpos))) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, size = 14, fill = "blue") +
  ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
```

[image]