# Creating barplot as showed in the image

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm new to ggplot2, creating basic things using barplot and geom command lines is fine to me but how I can get the shape of small squares representing each case of daily infection like in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. this is a duplicate question; have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468505/how-to-change-the-shape-of-dot-in-geom-dotplot-in-r.  When asking a questing have a read of [ask] and [mre] to see how the site works. It’s best to include the code you have tried as well as your data and what your expected outcome

Comment: While that is a duplicate, the solution in the linked post provides a hacked solution using `ggplot2` while the example in the pic appears to be in base graphics, which I wasn't able to find an example for and would also be keen to see.